# How to merge 2 arrays

Tags: r, merge

I'm trying to merge these array but I cannot get the idea
There's 'winequality_red' data, which has many rows & columns (1300x12)
I included image for understand the data
[sample_frac(winequality_red_s,frac=0.01)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3v0O.png)

[winequality_red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzsVI.png)

[stack(winequality_red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Pe6.png)

[what 'winequality_red' looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubhoL.png)

What I tried to do is : Randomly-sample the data(winequality_red) and make it NA
For this, What i did is :

```
winequality_red_s<-stack(winequality_red)
y<-sample_frac(winequality_red_s,0.01)
y[,1]<-NA
```

Next process is: I have to merge 2 data 'winequality_red_s' and 'y'
but I have no idea how can I merge those.
Of course I tried merge() function but it made new column which I didn't aim.

Comment: can you provide a subset of data?

Comment: When you say that you want to merge the two data sets, what do you mean? I think that you are saying that the two data sets have the same columns and you just want to add the rows of y after the rows of 'winequality_red_s.  Is that correct?  If so,  please look at `?rbind`.

Comment: G5W // What I tried to do is : sample randomly and make it into NA. For this, I stack() the data and sample_frac() and made it NA. So (update 'winequality_red_s' looking 'y') would be closer than (add) what I meant

Comment: Zmnako Awrahman  // I added the picture